# There exists a continuously differentiable bijection, $g:[a,b]\to [c,d]$ satisfying $g'(k)>0$ with $z(k)=w(g(k))$

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers

Let $z:[a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ and $w:[c,d]\to \mathbb{C}$ such that there exists $t(s):[c,d]\to [a,b]$ which is a continuously differentiable bijection with $t'(s)>0$ and $w(s)=z(t(s))$.

> Then I want to prove that there exists a continuously differentiable
>   bijection, $g:[a,b]\to [c,d]$ satisfying $g'(k)>0$ with
>   $z(k)=w(g(k))$.

I am guessing that this $g$ is $t^{-1}$ because $w(t^{-1}(k)=z(t(t^{-1})(k))=z(k)$ and as $t$ is a bijection, so $t^{-1}$ is also a bijection.

I don't know how to proceed after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already proved the part where you constructed $g$ (that is $t^{-1}$). So if is understand your question right all we need to prove is that $t^{-1}$ is continuously differentiable and that $t^{-1}(k)>0$.

You know that $t(t^{-1}(k)) = k$ so using the chain rule we have that:
$$t'(t^{-1}(k)) {t^{-1}}'(k)=1 \quad \Leftrightarrow {t^{-1}}'(k) = \frac{1}{t'(t^{-1}(k))}>0$$

Using this we may conclude that ${t^{-1}}'(k)>0$ and continuously differentiable.

Hope that helped.

**EDIT:**
Here's an argument for differentiability:
Note that (by the intermediate value theorem):
$$ 1 = \frac{t(t^{-1}(k+h))-t(t^{-1}(k))}{h} = t'(c_h) \left( \frac{t^{-1}(k+h) -t^{-1}(k)}{h}\right),$$
where $c_h$ belongs to the interval connecting $t^{-1}(k+h)$ and $t^{-1}(k)$. Note that we have that $c_h \to t^{-1}(k)$ as $h \to 0$. Thus we have that:
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{t^{-1}(k+h) -t^{-1}(k)}{h}\right) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{t'(c_h)} = \frac{1}{t'(t^{-1}(k)}$$
Where we have used continuity of $t'$ when passing the limit inside $t'$.

Comment: But how did we conclude that $(t^{-1})(k)$ is differentiable?

Comment: Your right that is rather unclear - a quick and ugly fix is to invoke the inverse function theorem locally at each point (since we know the bijection exist we only need the derivative part of the inverse function theorem). 

A cleaner argument would be to look for the derivative argument in the inverse function theorem, and use that directly.

Comment: is there a proof for $f$ from some (a,b) to R that I can read?

Comment: Just added it :)

Comment: Thank you! Other resources pointing to the general proof use more tools.